# How to make signed request to Salesforce using an Access token and SOAP api?

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, integration

I'm working on `Salesforce integration` to **(1)** upload file attachments to Salesforce and **(2)** make signed requests/API call to Salesforce using the access token that we already have. Uploading files to SF using REST is not an option for us since we are not in pilot program as describe [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm). So we used Beatbox to [upload files to SF](http://www.ronbeltran.com/2014/01/how-to-upload-file-attachments-to-salesforce-with-python.html) and that uses SOAP api. Now since we're using Beatbox we also wanted to make signed request to SF API using an access token that we already have. Looking at Beatbox source there is `useSession(sessionId, serverUrl)`, now I can replace `sessionId` with `access token` and put a hard coded server url and I can make signed request to SF with that, problem is `serverUrl` is changing. Using just the access token can I get the serverUrl in advance so that I can use it with `useSession()`? If not possible, what are other alternatives?

Update: I added a simple helper method to beatbox.py for our requirement though some might find it useful. Credits to metadaddy for the solution.

```
def oauth_login(self, sessionId, orgId, userId):
    url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/id/%s/%s' % (orgId, userId)
    headers = { 
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % sessionId 
    }   
    params = {'version':'latest'}
    resp = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
    content = json.loads(resp.content)
    serverUrl = str(content.get('urls')['partner']).encode('UTF-8')
    self.useSession(sessionId, serverUrl)
```

Usage:

```
import beatbox
sf = beatbox._tPartnerNS
svc = beatbox.Client()

access_token = ''
orgId = ''
userId = ''

svc.oauth_login(access_token, orgId, userId)
qr = svc.query("select Id, Name from Account")
print "query size = " + str(qr[sf.size])
```

Comment: How are you getting the access token? OAuth 2.0?

Comment: Yes it is from OAuth 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OAuth 2.0 response includes the `id` property, which is a URL for the Identity Service, with the format

`https://login.salesforce.com/id/[ORG_ID]/[USER_ID]`

Invoke this URL with the access token, and you'll receive a JSON object with a bunch of useful data including the Partner API server URL. I don't have a Python example handy, but here's an example using command-line curl. Note the `-L` parameter - you need to follow the redirect, and the `version=latest` query parameter just says you want the latest API version URLs:

```
$ curl -L -H 'Authorization: Bearer 00DE0000000HegH!AREAQBXmi3kZkq.14qNdqVUAhdmdj8jCvSnZhsdDck.xhFwoaxUdgG6fiqY3OKebwLQoRnSudnpNHsrC30xaqk8R8ZRX1eJS' -H 'X-PrettyPrint: 1' https://login.salesforce.com/id/00DE0000000HegHMAS/005E0000000HiFiIAK?version=latest
{
  "id" : "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00DE0000000HegHMAS/005E0000000HiFiIAK",
  "asserted_user" : true,
  "user_id" : "005E0000000HiFiIAK",
  "organization_id" : "00DE0000000HegHMAS",
  "username" : "pat@devorg.com",
  "nick_name" : "pat1.2979659540664607E12",
  "display_name" : "Pat Patterson",
  "email" : "ppatterson@salesforce.com",
  "first_name" : "Pat",
  "last_name" : "Patterson",
  "status" : {
    "created_date" : null,
    "body" : null
  },
  "photos" : {
    "picture" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed--c.na9.content.force.com/profilephoto/729E0000000Ubc9/F",
    "thumbnail" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed--c.na9.content.force.com/profilephoto/729E0000000Ubc9/T"
  },
  "urls" : {
    "enterprise" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/29.0/00DE0000000HegH",
    "metadata" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/29.0/00DE0000000HegH",
    "partner" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0/00DE0000000HegH",
    "rest" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/",
    "sobjects" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/",
    "search" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/search/",
    "query" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/query/",
    "recent" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/recent/",
    "profile" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/005E0000000HiFiIAK",
    "feeds" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/chatter/feeds",
    "groups" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/chatter/groups",
    "users" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/chatter/users",
    "feed_items" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/chatter/feed-items",
    "custom_domain" : "https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com"
  },
  "active" : true,
  "user_type" : "STANDARD",
  "language" : "en_US",
  "locale" : "en_US",
  "utcOffset" : -28800000,
  "last_modified_date" : "2013-06-19T17:19:41.000+0000"
}
```

The URL you are looking for is `urls.partner`, which is `https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0/00DE0000000HegH` in the above example.

Comment: Can you help me out on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53716/instance-url-related-error-when-connecting-to-soap-api-using-access-token-in-pyt

Comment: @HussainTamboli Done